# Add docker arguments to gcloud builds submit

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-build), it's possible to submit a Dockerfile build using `gcloud builds submit -t <source>`. However, is it possible to pass additional build args to it? I tried `gcloud builds sumbit -t <source> --build-arg=FOO=$BAR` but it didn't recognize the flags. The old `gcloud docker` command use to support pass-through of docker args. I don't want to use a `cloudbuild.yaml` file if I can avoid it since I'm relying on Azure DevOps for the build and don't want to clutter up my repo with more YAML pipeline files.

My use case is that I want to leverage google cloud build's layer caching for faster builds since Azure DevOps doesn't have that built-in.

Comment: Is this what you need [Substituting variable values](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass some argument to Cloud Build with the `-t` argument docker build. Only `cloudbuild.yaml` config file accepts variables